# How to setup max value for performance tests in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, performance, performance-testing

When I run my performance test cases in XCode I can setup the baselines. If the measurements are different that the baselines it will fail.

Eg. the baseline is 1 sec. The test case will fail in case of:

- the measurement is 1.5 sec
- the measurement is 0.5 sec

I would like to see failure just in case the measurement is slower than the baseline (case 1.5 sec). If it's faster (case 0.5 sec) I am happy and I want to see green test cases. 
Is there any way to do this? Specify not a baseline but a max value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this question we must understand the XCodeTest's performance test. The testing will, in essence, record the following to two properties during a full test run:

- The average result of 10 test run measurements
- The standard deviation (indicating the spread of the measurements) of these test runs

The (auto-calculated) baseline is specified from a previous test run, and the test will fail if any of the two conditions are not met:

1. The average over a test run shall not increase more than 10% from the given baseline average (where baseline avarage is per-configurated and stored in source).
2. The standard deviation must not exceed a given percentage, say `max_STDDEV%` of average. The value `max_STDDEV` is set to 10% as default, by may be changed in the Performance Result GUI popup.

From the rules above, we realize that the reason that your tests seemingly failed when running "too quick" is not due to passing a specific lower bound value (0.5s), but rather that the *spread* of the measurements become too large, failing the standard deviation condition **2.** above.

One not so good way to attempt to redeem this would be to increase the allowed maximum standard deviation value for the measurements (`max_STDDEV`), but this is risky as solely relying on the average condition **1.** would allow for tests passing even for e.g. the following scenario (average equals baseline (1), but with a large std dev of 40%).

[image: Large STDDEV]
*(Image from first reference below, WWDC 2014 session)*

In terms of performance testing, you want to make sure to test implementations and algorithms that have a somewhat deterministic nature, such that the purpose of the test could be to spot performance-breaking language/API updates or new code implementations. If your scenario of testing is indeed as the one above, the in might be appropriate to carefully look it over, and possibly raise the maximum allowed standard deviation, after careful thought. E.g. for a stochastic algorithm, a large standard deviation could be allowed, relying more on the average performance. The danger testing e.g. stochastic algorithms with a large allowed stddev, however, is that only 10 tests is possible not sufficient to capture performance losses.

See also:

- [WWDC 2014 - Session 414 - Testing in Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/414/) (see the stream or the [presentation slides](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/414xx4l5du0f408/414/414_testing_in_xcode_6.pdf)),
- [Testing with Xcode - Running Tests and Viewing Results](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/05-running_tests.html)